# Unique Identifier For Elements of a List Parsed By ng-repeat in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to repeat through some list that is present in variable "`tab.excelFields`". I have been successfully able to do that, simple ng-repeat. The code is shown below:

```
<tr>
        <th ng-repeat="field in tab.excelFields" class="btn btn-danger" style="display:table-cell;" id="{{id}}">{{field}}</th>
</tr>
```

Notice {{id}} field. I need to put in unique values here...1,2,3 and so on

Question: How do I add unique id to each of these fields that I am displaying? Something like "id in [1,2,3]" in conjunction with my code. Two problems:-

1. How to give "`id in [1,2,3]`" with "`field in tab.excelFields`" in `ng-repeat`? Can it take two arguments?
2. My fields are not restricted to any fixed number. It can be one or one thousand. How to dynamically create a counter and add to this for "`id`" field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$index` variable inside ngRepeat scope.

```
<th ng-repeat="field in tab.excelFields" class="btn btn-danger" style="display:table-cell;" id="{{$index}}">{{field}}</th>
```

Comment: The logic is correct, but `{{id}}` should hold a prefix and not a number alone, the risk of conflict will be high otherwise.

Comment: Never knew about {{$index}}. Thanks a ton mate!